# How can I get raw text output of a manual in my terminal

Tags: command-line, documentation

How can I get raw text output of a manual in my terminal?

I want to have the manual without a "less" type screen displayed.

Comment: What do you mean "raw text output"? There is a `-t` option to format the man page with `groff`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change the pager to `cat` using the `-P` option:

```
man -P cat command
```

where `command` is the command of interest whose man page you wish to read.

You can also redirect the man page to a file which you can then open to read:

```
man command > file
```

Answer (score 4):

You can directly read the compressed (could be uncompressed too) `man` files, residing under `/usr/share/man/` in directories corresponding to respective sections.

So for example, to get the raw content of `man` page of `cat`, you need to read `/usr/share/man/man1/cat.1.gz`:

```
zcat /usr/share/man/man1/cat.1.gz
```

Similarly, for `man 2 fork`:

```
zcat /usr/share/man/man2/fork.2.gz
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a text format, AND you don't want those pesky "page separators" everywhere in the document, a way is:

```
zcat /usr/share/man/en/man1/man.1.gz | groff -m man -rcR=1 -T ascii -
```

(change `/usr/share/man/en/man1/man.1.gz` to the manpage you are looking for. This is is the man page for man (same as : `man man`, but without the page separators)

There is a way to do a custom man command that does the same for you, but I can't test it right now...

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting `man`'s output (as suggested in other answers) should work as expected. `man` detects that its output is not a tty, so it avoids printing appropriate escape characters that would otherwise provide *italics*, **bold** and other formatting.

As a more general answer, you can use `col -b` to strip such characters from the output of any command. Not all commands are as smart as `man` and might not detect that their output is being redirected. In other words, you could have done something like:

```
man command | col -b > somefile
```